# Can you replace a 15.6" laptop display with a different display?

Tags: display

I'm getting [this laptop](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834316154&ignorebbr=1), and the main drawback I've heard about it is that the display is too dim and unsaturated. If I were to find another 15.6" screen with better color and brightness, would I be able to just swap it out? I've replaced laptop screens before, however I'm not sure if a different model makes a difference.

Comment: Why not just pick a laptop that has a screen you like better?  Even if you could find a better compatible replacement screen (unlikely), you'll end up spending more than just buying a better laptop (and it will void the warranty).

Comment: @fixer1234 I have a $780 newegg gift card, and the choices are very limited on newegg

Comment: There are places where you can sell gift cards (they typically take 10%-15%), like https://giftcardzen.com/, https://www.cardpool.com/, and https://www.giftcards.com/, or you can sell them on eBay.  You would be better off converting it to cash at the small reduction and then buying what you need.

Comment: @fixer1234 That's like $100 off my gift card though. Plus, there's some more stuff I want to get on NewEgg

Answer (score 0):

The interface used to connect laptop displays is called LVDS.Unless you can find an exact part number or model code for the screen, it should be ruled as incompatible.They may use the same connector, but there is a chance of them not using the same pinouts.

Manufacturers usually use different pins for each model even though they're the same connector.

Compatible screens are pretty rare, So, I recommend using external monitor for your laptop being the safe move, but if you are traveling often with the laptop and you want better color and brightness during that ,you need to risk finding the screen with same connector with exact pinouts.